# Strange Node await never unblocks

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

Node v8.3 + Express + using `async` / `await` complete source code below where `await` doesn't return unless I moved the terminal!!

```
// Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Lodash
const _ = require('lodash');

// DBR
const dbr = require('./build/Release/dbr');
dbr.initLicense("t0068MgAAAGvV3VqfqOzkuVGi7x/PFfZUQoUyJOakuduaSEoI2Pc8+kMwjrojxQgE5aJphmhagRmq/S9lppTkM4w3qCQezxk=");

// Promisify
const {promisify} = require('util');
const decodeFilePromise = promisify(dbr.decodeFileAsync);

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Received a barcode scan request!");
    try {
        const oneDimensionType = 0x3FF;
        const scannedResults = await decodeFilePromise('test.jpg', oneDimensionType);

        const imeiResults = _.uniq(_.map(_.filter(scannedResults, ['format', 'CODE_128']), 'value'));
        console.log(`Successfully scanned the image: ${imeiResults}`);

        res.send(`IMEI results: ${imeiResults}`);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(`Failed to scan the image: ${err}`);
        res.send('Could not scan the barcode!');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

What do I mean by "unless I moved the terminal" ? Please see the attached GIF: https://youtu.be/HW_MqLzEC9M

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post GIF from CloudApp. Here's the GIF: https:// cl.ly/mcb6  (Please remove the extra space between `//` and `cl`

Comment: Is this behavior repeated for any other asynchronous function? For example, for fs.readFile?

Comment: Let me try that. @stdob--

Comment: Resizing a terminal sends particular signals to a process. Perhaps the library you're using relies on those, for some reason. However, it's hard to say without the library code; is that available from somewhere?